# Embedded Unity3D in WPF Application -> SetWindowLong issues

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, styles, host

I'm developping an application in WPF that host an Unity application.
This hosting is set by using a HwndHost class (because the unity way with the _hwndparent argument seems don(t work).

In the BuilWindowCore of my HwndHost class, I need to change the window child style using GetWindowLong and SetWindowLong.

All of these works perfectly on my developping computer. But I can't use the application on another computer.

When I just set WS_CCHILD value (without retrieving the style using GetWindowLong) ther isn't crash on all computers, but the child application not appeared correctly (Maximized etc..). That's why I think the problem is about the styling child window part.

There is my HwndHost class code:

```
public class UnityHwndHost : HwndHost
{
    private Process _process;
    private HandleRef _hwnd;
    private IntPtr _unityHWND; // = IntPtr.Zero;

    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

    // Window Styles 
    const UInt32 WS_OVERLAPPED = 0;
    const UInt32 WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
    const UInt32 WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    const UInt32 WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000;
    const UInt32 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    const UInt32 WS_DISABLED = 0x8000000;
    const UInt32 WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x4000000;
    const UInt32 WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x2000000;
    const UInt32 WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x1000000;
    const UInt32 WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;      // WS_BORDER or WS_DLGFRAME  
    const UInt32 WS_BORDER = 0x800000;
    const UInt32 WS_DLGFRAME = 0x400000;
    const UInt32 WS_VSCROLL = 0x200000;
    const UInt32 WS_HSCROLL = 0x100000;
    const UInt32 WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
    const UInt32 WS_THICKFRAME = 0x40000;
    const UInt32 WS_GROUP = 0x20000;
    const UInt32 WS_TABSTOP = 0x10000;
    const UInt32 WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
    const UInt32 WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;
    const UInt32 WS_TILED = WS_OVERLAPPED;
    const UInt32 WS_ICONIC = WS_MINIMIZE;
    const UInt32 WS_SIZEBOX = WS_THICKFRAME;

    // Extended Window Styles 
    const UInt32 WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY = 0x0004;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x0008;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES = 0x0010;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x0020;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_MDICHILD = 0x0040;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x0080;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE = 0x0100;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x0200;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP = 0x0400;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x1000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_LEFT = 0x0000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_RTLREADING = 0x2000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_LTRREADING = 0x0000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR = 0x4000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR = 0x0000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT = 0x10000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_STATICEDGE = 0x20000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x40000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = (WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
    const UInt32 WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW = (WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST);
    const UInt32 WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = 0x00100000; // Disable inheritence of mirroring by children
    const UInt32 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x00400000; // Right to left mirroring
    const UInt32 WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;
    const UInt32 WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;


    private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
    private readonly IntPtr WA_ACTIVE = new IntPtr(1);
    private readonly IntPtr WA_INACTIVE = new IntPtr(0);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, UInt32 dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndParent);

    internal delegate int WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc func, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    #region CONSTRUCTORS
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        var context = DataContext as UltrasoundVM;
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("UnityStandAlone.exe");

        psi.Arguments = "\"" + context.Workspace.Replace('\\', '/') + "\" " + context.SelectedFlexible;
        LoggerHelper.Write(GetType().FullName + "." + new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name + " : " + psi.Arguments, EventLogEntryType.Information);
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        _process = Process.Start(psi);
        _process.WaitForInputIdle();
        while (_process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero || !IsWindow(_process.MainWindowHandle))
        {
            Thread.Yield();
        }
        _unityHWND = _process.MainWindowHandle;
        SetParent(_unityHWND, hwndParent.Handle);

        var style = GetWindowLong(_unityHWND, GWL_STYLE);
        style = style & ~WS_CAPTION & ~WS_THICKFRAME; // Removes Caption bar and the sizing border
        style |= (WS_CHILD); // Must be a child window to be hosted
        SetWindowLong(_unityHWND, GWL_STYLE, style);

        SetWindowLong(_unityHWND, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD | WS_MAXIMIZE);

        SendMessage(_unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);

        _hwnd = new HandleRef(this, _unityHWND);
        return _hwnd;
    }

    protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
    {
        SendMessage(_hwnd.Handle, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_INACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);

        _process.CloseMainWindow();

        _process.WaitForExit(5000);

        if (_process.HasExited == false)
        {
            _process.Kill();
        }

        _process.Close();
        _process.Dispose();
        _process = null;
    }
    #endregion   
}
```

**Notes:**

Developping Computer
- OS : Windows 10 Home edition
- Unity 3D 5.5.2.f.1 free edition

Testing Computers
- OS : Windows 10 (Home edition & Pro Edition)

Of course I've tried to build the unity application with different parameters, same thing with my parent application.

Comment: _"because the unity way with the _hwndparent argument seems don(t work"_ ... That's how it works. It allows specified window handle to child Unity's window... without this argument it will throw exceptions and wont behave as expected.

Comment: Do you have a working sample ? because the official unity sample (the one with the cube) doesn't work...

Comment: just add `-parentHWND <wpf_handle>` to your parameters... After this everything should work as intended.

Comment: I've tested again the -hwndParent way and it doesn't work... Nothing appears and no error... My problem is 1) the official sample doesn't work so I can't realize a solution based on it...and 2) my way works but not on all computers... that I don't understand... I would like to use the official way of course but I don't succeed.

Comment: What's your build target ? Desktop?

Comment: Yes Windows Stand alone x86_64

Comment: And your C# WPF project is set up for 64bit ?

Comment: Yes... And I've tried with other parameters to be sure

Answer (score 1):

OK

It seems that the problem came from my unity stand alone which was not the same between my sources and my debug folder.

Comment: Can you provide a whole solution if not a problem somehow?